# How to make a GUI window which shows Linux commands getting executed?

Tags: shell-script

I have made a software in shell scripting and I wanted it to be simple for the user to install it so, I've made a GUI in python but in my software, it executes few Linux commands which the user has to see. In Ubuntu installation view image for more info if you click the triangle near the copying files you'll get a console that's exactly how I wanted.**Live console **[image]

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to set PS4 to "$ " and set command echo in your script, run your script in background with output redirection to a file and read and display that file in the GUI as long as the script is running.

Example script install.sh:

```
PS4='$ '
set -x
echo "testing..."
pwd
ls
```

From shell execute "`./install.sh > output.txt`" to see what I mean.

Comment: Thank you @Akilan! But this is not I want, I want a live console again Live. But anyways this is not a bad answer and I can use it somewhere else once again thank you!

Comment: Live console? You want user to enter commands after you are done with? Because in Ubuntu install that is not possible.

Comment: Not exactly Live console but should show the commands getting executed live. Sorry! That's what I meant.

Comment: You can read that file live & display. Or you can open a pipe from the shell script using popen. Search about it or ask in stackoverflow or python community.

Comment: How do you save the file and display it live can you provide some links please!

Comment: Please @Akilan! Tell me a way to do this.